# Force deserialization to use custom converter when using TypeNameHandling.All Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a problem with json.net 9.0.1 to do with custom converters. Let's say I have a class with a readonly array as a field.

```
public class ClassWithArray
{
    public readonly int[] NumbersArray;

    public ClassWithArray(int[] numbersArray)
    {
        NumbersArray = numbersArray;
    }
}
```

And a subclass of this which has an array predefined.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(SubClassConverter))]
public class SubClass : ClassWithArray
{
    public readonly string  Name;
    public SubClass(string name) : base(new [] {1, 2, 3})
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

And the JsonConverter:

```
public class SubClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        return new SubClass(jObject["Name"].ToObject<string>());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(SubClass) == objectType;
    }
}
```

With the `JsonConverter` attribute I would assume that if you serialize and deserialize with the `TypeNameHandling.All` setting on then you would get an object back that uses `SubClassConverter` for construction. However this is not the case all the time (at least it doesn't make it that far).

The following code that uses the generic deserialize method to specify the type will work fine:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GenericDeserialize()
{
    SubClass original = new SubClass("Foo");
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original, serializerSettings);
    SubClass clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SubClass>(json, serializerSettings);

    MakeAssertions(clone);
}
```

However the following code which doesn't specify a type will fail with a `System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SettingsOnBoth()
{
    SubClass original = new SubClass("Foo");
    var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original, serializerSettings);
    object clone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, serializerSettings); //System.NotSupportedException: Collection was of a fixed size.

    MakeAssertions(clone);
}
```

In my project I need to be able to deserialize an object that subclasses a class similar to the `ClassWithArray` object above using the type from the json in combination with a converter as I have multiple subtypes. Am I missing a setting here or is there a way I can work around this limitation?

Full test code showing the problem [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cb570aaa76ae6819bbe84659864a739a)